# Add spaces to elements of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've been struggling for a while with this. I have a list with sublist and I wanted to add an element that is a space before  each element of the sublists. for example:

```
lin = [[2], [3], [2], [2, 2], [2]]
```

the result should be:

```
lin = [[' ',2], [' ',3], [' ',2], [' ',2, ' ',2], [' ',2]]
```

I've tried to do this:

```
for a in lin:
    for e in a:
        e = (' ') , e
```

but I obtained exactly the same list with no alterations

Comment: Do you mean `lin=[[' ',2], [' ',3], [' ',2], [' ',2, ' ',2], [' ',2]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you actually meant something like the comment of Tigerhawk.

Your problem is that `e= (' ') , e` is just overwriting the value of `e` (which was originally each value in your nested list) to a tuple containing a space and the original value. This doesnt actually change anything inside of your list, just changes whatever it is that `e` was originally pointing to.

You can instead do something like this:

```
>>> lin = [[2], [3], [2], [2, 2], [2]]
>>> for a in lin:
        for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
            a.insert(i, ' ')


>>> lin
[[' ', 2], [' ', 3], [' ', 2], [' ', 2, ' ', 2], [' ', 2]]
```

Note the inner loop: `for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):` This is done this way because of 2 reasons:

1. you dont want to be actually looping through `a` since you are going to be changin the values in `a`
2. You need to start with the highest index because if you start from 0, the indexes of the rest of the items ahead of it will change.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the `[2, 2]` element in there. Good work *Stomach Whisperer*

Comment: Uh oh. The name is sticking.

Comment: thank you so much for your help and for the explanation! yes I wanted to mean what Tigerhawk said. Thanks again I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension and `chain.from_iterable` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lin = [[2], [3], [2], [2, 2], [2]]
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable([(' ', i) for i in j])) for j in lin]
[[' ', 2], [' ', 3], [' ', 2], [' ', 2, ' ', 2], [' ', 2]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat, functional solution, that uses only built-in functions

```
lin = [[2], [3], [2], [2, 2], [2]]

add_spaces = lambda l: [i for x in zip(' '*len(l), l) for i in x]
new_list = [add_spaces(l) for l in lin]
```

Output:

```
>>> print new_list
[[' ', 2], [' ', 3], [' ', 2], [' ', 2, ' ', 2], [' ', 2]]
```

Comment: moar functions! `lambda l: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.repeat(' '), l)))`

Comment: (and I'm very happy that it worked, since I whipped it together without running it through my repr first...)