# Insert an element before and after a specific element in a List of strings

Tags: python, list, iteration

Is it possible to insert to a list when a specific string appears.
Example:

```
List=['north','south','east','west','south','united']
```

So for every time the string 'south' is presented the list will be insert an item `'canada'` before the element south in the list.

```
Results
List=['north','canada','south','east','west','canada','south','united']
```

EDIT: I apologize for not being specific enough.  I need it to seek the specific characters.

```
List1=['north','<usa>23<\usa>','east','west','<usa>1942<\usa>','united']
Result=['north','canada', '<usa>23<\usa>','east','west','canada','<usa>1942<\usa>','united']
```

Comment: you are looking for `insert`, not `append`. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099329/add-spaces-to-elements-of-list/34099402?noredirect=1#comment55950963_34099402) may help, though you will have to put a conditional statement in your list traversal

Comment: Are you sure it is `<\usa>` and not `</usa>`?

Answer (score 13):

To be able to place elements within a list in specific positions, you need to list `insert` function.

```
<list>.insert(<position>, <value>)
```

As an example, if you have a list containing the following:

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

And want to add 10 in the list but maintain the current order, you can do:

```
a.insert(4, 10)
```

and will get:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

**EDIT**

To insert before every 'south' do:

```
for i in range(len(<list>)):
    if <list>[i] == 'south':
        <list>.insert(i, 'canada')
```

Comment: This does not really answers the question I think?

Comment: I understand the insert function but for how do I insert it a new element to my list before every element that says 'south'

Comment: Do you think the cycle `for i in range(len(..))` could really work? I think you should go backwards, not to move items which are not handled yet. In addition use of `enumerate()` would be nice.

Answer (score 9):

Inserting element before another

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x.insert(x.index(4), 22)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 22, 4, 5]
```

Inserting element after another

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x.insert(x.index(3)+1, 22)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 22, 4, 5]
```

However, this does not work for multiple insertions

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,6,4,7]
>>> x.insert(x.index(4), 22)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 22, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer:

```
def blame_canada(old_list): 
    new_list = []
    for each in old_list:
        if each == 'south':
            new_list.append('canada')
        new_list.append(each)
    return new_list
```

Comment: Don't need the `else`; you're appending `each` in either branch, so make it unconditional.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple one-liner using double *list comprehension* (using `List` like you defined it):

```
>>> [inner for outer in [(['canada',x] if x == 'south' else [x]) for x in List] for inner in outer]
['north', 'canada', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'canada', 'south', 'united']
```

The answers consists out of two parts:

- the inner list comprehension: `[(['canada',x] if x == 'south' else [x]) for x in List]` this iterates over the list and returns a list of lists. In case `x` is south, it emits `['canada','south']`, otherwise it emits `[x]`. So the result is something like:

  ```
  >>> [(['canada',x] if x == 'south' else [x]) for x in List]
  [['north'], ['canada', 'south'], ['east'], ['west'], ['canada', 'south'], ['united']]
  ```

  for the given list.
- Next the result is flattened using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/716761/67579).

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple loop:

```
L = ['north','south','east','west','south','united']
res = []
for entry in L:
    if entry == 'south':
        res.append('canada')
    res.append(entry)
L[:] = res
```

The last line copies the result into the original list. This makes it equivalent to `append` that modifies the original list. Using a lot of `insert` calls would make it really slow for large list as it need to build the whole lists for each insert.

Comment: I didn't specify that well but I understand this, I am looking if it contains these letters. Then I would append because on my actually list there will be numbers appended to the seeking element .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a high-performance list-comprehension method for doing this.

First, it generates a list of indexes containing "south".

Then, it uses the index + index-order for the insertion point (to account for previous insertions in the loop), making for a simple, yet quick and easy-to-follow pythonic solution for this problem:

```
List = ['north','south','east','west','south','united']
souths = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(List) if val == 'south']
for i, idx in enumerate(souths):
    List.insert(idx+i, 'canada')
```

Comment: What makes you call this high-performance? Did you do timing tests, or you just think it's high-performance?

Comment: @dwanderson you don't need to test it to know the computational complexity is approximately O(1.25n).